# using batch to merge files into one file using parameters

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to merge set of text files from a folder defined by the first input parameter to the script.

```
FOR /r %%Y IN (%1\*.txt) DO (
    copy /b %1\%%Y %1\mergeTsum.txt
)
```

I feel that there is something very obvious that I am missing in relation to using parameters with commands

Answer (score 4):

`copy`does not append to the destination (well, it can, but not with your syntax)
(`copy /b file1+file2+file3 result`)
It would be easyer here to use `type` instead of `copy`

```
FOR /r %%Y IN (%1\*.txt) DO (
    type %1\%%Y >>%1\mergeTsum.tmp
)
ren %1\mergeTsum.tmp mergeTsum.txt
```

Comment: Your for command has a problem. Since mergeTsum.txt is in the same directory that the rest of the files, it will be included in the list of readed files and the content of previous processed files will be duplicated.